# C# я новичек задание в soloream и не понимаю в чем ошибка

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SoloLearn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int points = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

           if (points <= 80)
           {
             Console.WriteLine("Level completed");  
           }
           else 
           {
               Console.WriteLine(Extra gift);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует автору проверяющей системы

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или *ошибку* и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопрос. Что за ошибка - не указано.

Comment: Пробовали запускать код у себя, не в sololearn?

Answer (score 2):

```
 Console.WriteLine("Extra gift");
```

В ином случае вы пытаетесь передать в метод две переменные под именем `Extra` и `gift`, которые метод всё равно не сможет исполнить, даже если бы они были, потому что они разделены пробелом.

Comment: @aepot да, спасибо. на автомате получилось из другого языка)